# Does WinLicense slow down the program?

Tags: c#

I noticed, after i packed with WinLicense, the file is bigger. I don't care about the size. I am worrying about the performance .

My question, ex. I run my packed program ? i noticed, the software start up is bit slower, but i wonder , does the logic is the software running as normal after it loaded ?

Answer (score 0):

Run your app through a profiler.  If the profiler shows any WinLicense code running after startup, that will give you a definitive answer.

red-gate makes a good profiler, ANTS.  http://www.red-gate.com/products/ants_performance_profiler